# Setting and Config information management in C#

Tags: c#

Setting and Config information management in C#
program logic and UI
Affected by applying in Setting.cs file

Below is my current code

Setting.cs

```
bool isChecked; 
isChecked = checkBox1.Checked;
```

Main.cs

```
Setting setting = New Setting();
if(setting.isCheck)
```

But there is a possibility to use it in several classes and cs files.

So I am trying to change the structure like the code below.

Static Class
Config.cs

```
Static bool isChecked {get; set;}
```

Setting.cs

```
Config.isChecked = checkBox1.Checked;
```

Main.cs

```
if(Config.isChecked)
```

If used in many
It seems to be good to manage with Static.

I am trying to change to the second of the first and second methods.
What is the problem with my code?
Do you have any better ideas?

Comment: "What is the problem with my code?" You have a problem?

Comment: Currently there is no problem.
However, in the structure of managing the Config and Setting information I want
I wonder if there are any problems or management difficulties.
Both method 1 and method 2

Comment: Maybe it helps you looking how the system build in settings handling works. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2022

Comment: Good documentation, but I have a question
another idea,
 Whether it's a good idea to switch from Method 1 to Method 2 and how to manage it in general.

Comment: We can't answer that. That is dependent on context we don't have. If you want a general answer if its for learning try all the methods you can think of and compare them. Another one you might try is implementing your settings as singleton. If that is for actual use take whats already there and implemented. Those things typically work has been used by millions of people and has been proven to work. Its nothing someone implements then just because he can.

Comment: What type of project are we talking about? It _seems_ to be WinForms?